# run java applet in html-file?

Tags: java, html, applet

I made a java class made Spel.java, if I compile the file I get 3 class-files Spel$1.class, Spel$SpelTimerTask.class and Spel.class.

These three classes together create my graphical game. So if I make my html-code like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code="Spel.class" width="600" height="400"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

My game won't play because I only use one class and if I make my html-code like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code="Spel$1.class" width="600" height="400"></applet>
<applet code="Spel$SpelTimerTask.class" width="600" height="400"></applet>
<applet code="Spel.class" width="600" height="400"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

3 different applets pop-up so how can I solve this problem and get those 3 classes in one applet?

Comment: Why are you making an applet? Read [this](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). As for your question, you either need the other classes to be on the applet's classpath - this means in the same folder on the webserver - or package them into a Jar.

Comment: Ok, I made a jar-file and it works when I run it on my computer but when i want to run it on my html-file I get a RuntimeException, do you know why?